# iOS and Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: ios, ios5, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I know that there are a lot of restrictions on bluetooth when it comes to iOS. I wanted some more information on Bluetooth Low Energy (LE) and the CoreBluetooth Framework apple provides from iOS 5.0 and greater.

1. Can i connect ANY Bluetooth LE device to an iOS device using the Core Bluetooth Framework?
2. Is there any Bluetooth LE device in production,that comes with a three axis accelerometer and a gyro that i could use like a Human Interface device?

Comment: With respect to #2, absolutely! Have a look at the TI [CC2540 Mini Dev Kit](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2540dk-mini).

Comment: Just checked out, but it seems like you need a dongle (which comes with its own software) to communicate with the slave. I was looking at something like this.  http://hillcrestlabs.com/products/downloads/1000-2538-FSRK-BT-1-Product-Brief-v1.2.pdf 

Basically, the interface should be BT RF and not a USB dongle as i want to write my own software to drive the device.

Comment: The USB dongle is purely for convenience during your development. The CC2540 chip itself is tiny and can be included in any devices you create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sagar, Maybe you can explain more about what you want to do.

Any BT4.0 LE device can connect and communicate with a iOS app using the CoreBluetooth Framework.

The CC2540 dev kit does contain a fob that has accelerometer, it does not have a gyro.

The USB dongle that comes with the kit is for communicating with the fob from a PC/Mac, you do not need it for communicating with the iOS device.

Comment: The idea basically is to use a BT4.0 LE device and communicate with an iOS device. 
I want to pull the accelerometer and gyro data (motion data) and read it on an iOS device. 
The big picture, is to use such a BT4.0 LE device as probably a joystick (more like the wii) for an iOS device for my app!

Comment: I don't think you'll need a gyro for that

Comment: Actually a gyro is exactly what he needs for a wii-like remote.

Comment: Yep, i need a gyro but what i wanted to know is IF the BT stack was open for BTLE devices from iOS 5 (and iPhone 4S) onwards? So that i could establish a communication channel between the phone and the BTLE device and actually access the data my BTLE device was transmitting!