# Can't seem to get core bluetooth to work

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I can't seem to get core bluetooth working on my iPad.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
{
    CBCentralManager *manager;
}
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textField;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize textField;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {
    textField.text = @"";

    if (manager.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        textField.text = @"Scanning...";
        NSLog(@"scanning");
        [manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
    } else {
        textField.text = @"Error";
    }
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    NSLog(@"2");
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@\n", textField.text, peripheral.name];
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    NSLog(@"d");
}

@end
```

`2` never gets logged and devices are never detected.  I made sure that bluetooth is enabled in my settings.

What's wrong with the code?  Could it just be that no applicable devices are discovered?  I can discover my iMac just fine in bluetooth settings.

Also, can Core Bluetooth (running on a device with bluetooth LE) detect non bluetooth LE devices?  Such as a wireless headset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Bluetooth only works with Bluetooth Low Energy and the code you have will only discover peripheral BLE devices, like BLE tags, heart rate monitors, sensors or [iOS 6 devices in peripheral mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857143/bluetooth-connection-between-2-ios-devices/13860235#13860235).

So no, you can't detect your iMac (OS X still has no peripheral mode via Core Bluetooth) or wireless headset this way. Or any other way with official SDK.

Comment: Are you sure that you can't do this thing with Mac OS X ? My MacBookAir has a BLE-chip. And it seems that CoreBluetooth with Peripheral&Central works at least on 10.7...

Comment: Core Bluetooth on Mac OS X 10.7 and iOS 5 only supports central mode. iOS 6 supports peripheral mode, but 10.8 still does not. So you can connect to a Bluetooth Low Energy peripheral using iOS 5 or later or OS X 10.7 or later, but you can only act as peripheral device using iOS 6.

Comment: The easiest way to confirm this is `NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(NA, 6_0)` in `CBPeripheralManager` header file (first argument is OS X, second is iOS version -> `NA` means it's not supported on Mac). Also, you can find WWDC videos in answer I linked above where this is described in better detail as documentation is really poor on this.

Comment: FYI, CBPeripheralManager is available on OS X as of Mavericks (10.9).

Comment: I got around the "no BTLE in iOS simulator" problem by building a little OS X app. Running locally, there's no need to get an OS X development license. That said, the BTLE stuff is not included in CoreBluetooth, but under the greater OS X bluetooth umbrella: IOBluetooth. Be sure to import this framework, and you'll have access to all the CoreBluetooth goodness. Your iOS dev knowledge will transfer over well, and you'll be up and running in half an hour or less.