# Still can't get CoreBluetooth to work in a simple name discovery app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth

I'm trying to make a simple application that will scan for nearby Bluetooth devices and list their names as they are discovered. I'm using `CoreBluetooth` in accordance with every guide I've found, including Apple's guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH3-SW1)

However, it never works. I put an iPhone 4S in discoverable mode next to the iPhone 5 running the app, and it never discovers it. I also tried a Bluetooth-enabled car, but I don't know if it has BLE. What am I doing wrong? Here is the essence of my code, in `ViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [activity stopAnimating]; isScanning = NO; //activity is a GUI activity wheel
    centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate: self queue: nil];
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{
    int state = central.state;
    [self log: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"CBCentralManagerDidUpdateState: %d", state]];
//[self log] just NSLogs the message and adds it to a text view for the user to see.
    if (state!=CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
        [self log: @"Error! Bluetooth not powered on!"]; //I never get this error.
    }
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI{
    [self log: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Peripheral found with CoreBluetooth: %@", peripheral.name]];
//And I never see any of these "peripheral found" messages.
}

- (IBAction)scanButton:(id)sender {
    if (!isScanning){
        [activity startAnimating];
        isScanning = YES;
        [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
        [self log: @"Scanning started."];
    }
    else{
        [activity stopAnimating];
        isScanning = NO;
        [centralManager stopScan];
        [self log: @"Scanning stopped."];
    }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here: [Can't seem to get core bluetooth to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195322/cant-seem-to-get-core-bluetooth-to-work?rq=1)
I need an iOS device in peripheral mode or a BLE peripheral. Very annoying because basically no peripherals use BLE.

It works with my brother's iPhone 4S running a free app from the App Store called LightBlue. The app lets you put the device in peripheral mode... it's kind of the developer to put out a nice testing app like this.