# Using CoreBluetooth in iOS app

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am pretty new to Xcode and am pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to use the coreBluetooth framework.

I am trying to connect to a BLE device and exchange data with it.  I have gone through several examples, but I am having a hard time understanding everything.  Does anyone know of a very basic example or even a step-by-step tutorial on how to implement all of it?

Comment: check out the xcode docs, couple examples in there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857143/bluetooth-connection-between-2-ios-devices

Comment: Bob, the bluetooth framework is a little weird to work with. I see that you got a down vote. Its likely because you didnt show anything you did, or give us what you tried. Stack Overflow was really meant for developers to help other developers, not just paste code snippets for projects. Some people go downvote happy and never explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps to transfer file with bluetooth.

1. Add GameKit framework.
2. In .h file

   ```
   #import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
   ```
3. In .h file add delegate

   ```
   <GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate,GKSessionDelegate>
   ```
4. In .h file create two object.

   ```
   GKSession *currentSession;
   GKPeerPickerController *picke;
   ```
5. Run this code on both side to connect (pair) device.

   ```
   picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
   picker.delegate = self;
   picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
   filePath = fullfilePath;
   [picker show];
   ```
6. When connection done following method will be called.

   ```
   -(void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)pk 
        didConnectPeer:(NSString *)peerID 
        toSession:(GKSession *)session
   ```
7. Write following code to maintain session on both side in this
   method.

   ```
   currentSession = session;
   session.delegate = self;
   [session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
   picker.delegate = nil;
   [picker dismiss];
   ```
8. This code will send file.

   ```
   if(filePath)
   {
       NSData *zipFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
       if(currentSession)
       {
           [currentSession sendDataToAllPeers:zipFileData 
                  withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
       }
   }
   ```
9. This method will recive data.The field `NSData* data` have the data
   send by sender. You can do anything with that. you can parse display
   or save as you wish.

   ```
   - (void) receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer 
                inSession:(GKSession *)session context:(void *)context
   ```
10. Following two method help to maintain session.

    ```
     -(void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID 
               didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state
     {
         @try
         {
             int a = state;
             switch (a)
             {
                 case GKPeerStateConnected:
                     DDLogVerbose(@"connected");
                     break;
                 case GKPeerStateDisconnected:
                     DDLogVerbose(@"disconnected");
                     currentSession = nil;
                     break;
             }
         }@catch (NSException *exception)
         {
             DDLogError(@"Exception : %@", exception);
         }
     }

     -(void)session:(GKSession *)session didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
     {
         @try
         {
             DDLogError(@"%@", [error description]);
         }@catch (NSException *exception)
         {
             DDLogError(@"Exception : %@", exception);
         }
     }
    ```

**Note :** Replace DDLog statement with NSLog. All The best.

Comment: Sorry for bad format. I have tried but not able to format it properly. I be happy if someone can do it.

Comment: I edited your answer. Can you please go through and see if I missed anything? It was a long post. Also Please learn to [format code in stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). You are doing it in the wrong way

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Thanks to edit and this very usefull link

Comment: GameKit support BLE now?